# How to use joins with generic repository pattern - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have a `Generic Repository` like below which handles my `CRUD`, for a single entity its easy to use, problem starts when i try to join my `POCOs`.

Lets say I have these POCO, they are mapped using fluent api (many to many and One to many relation) :

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() 
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    //FKs 
    public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
    public int StdandardRefId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
public class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Many-To-Many
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasMany<Course>(s => s.Courses)
                .WithMany(c => c.Students)
                .Map(cs =>
                        {
                            cs.MapLeftKey("StudentRefId");
                            cs.MapRightKey("CourseRefId");
                            cs.ToTable("StudentCourse");
                        });
        //One-To-Many
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasRequired<Standard>(s => s.Standard)
                .WithMany(s => s.Students)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.StandardId);

}
```

Generic Repository:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class, IDisposable
{
    internal MyDbContext context;
    internal DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public Repository()
    {
        context = new MyDbContext();
        this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public bool Add(T entity)
    {
        var query = dbSet.Add(entity);

        if (query != null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public bool Update(T entity)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        var query = context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

        if (query == EntityState.Modified)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public bool Delete(T entity)
    {
        var query = dbSet.Remove(entity);

        if (query != null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public bool Delete(Guid id)
    {
        var query = dbSet.Remove(dbSet.Find(id));

        if (query != null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public T GetById(Guid id)
    {
        var query = dbSet.Find(id);

        if (query != null)
            return query;
        else
            return null;
    }
    public ICollection<T> GetAll()
    {
        return dbSet.AsEnumerable<T>().ToList();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            context.Dispose();
            context = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now if i want to join Standard to Many-to-Many Table how may i be able to do this?

Comment: I see this question appear over and over again, but still don't understand why people use generic repository pattern with EF. Looks completely useless to me, and as you see only brings unnecessary headache.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit, please? I don't see how you'd want to join these two tables, or why.

Comment: @Evk so you suggest not using generic repository? may i ask why

Comment: Well that's I should ask you why you are using it. You cannot make any complex queries, even simple join. To update two different entities you have to create two repositories and open 2 database connections, and even wrap that into transaction. Only drawbacks with almost zero benefits.  Does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So based on your edit, I'm assuming you would like to join Students and Standards.

The first thing you have to do is change the repository so that it doesn't instantiate the context. You should pass that in as a parameter and store a reference to it:

```
public Repository(MyDbContext myCtx)
{
    context = myCtx;
    this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
}
```

The second thing you have to do is change your repository to change the `GetAll()` method to return `IQueryable<T>` instead of `ICollection<T>`.

Then change the implementation of `GetAll()`:

```
return dbSet;
```

This way you only get back a query and not the evaluated list of all the entities. And then you can do the join with the `GetAll()` method of the repositories just like you would do it with the db sets:

```
using (MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
  var studentRep = new Repository<Student>(ctx);
  var standardRep = new Repository<Standard>(ctx);
  var studentToStandard = studentRep.GetAll().Join(standardRep.GetAll(), 
                        student => student.StandardRefId,
                        standard => standard.StandardId,
                        (stud, stand) => new { Student=stud, Standard=stand }).ToList();
}
```

With this you get an `IQueryable<T>` in `studentToStandard`, which will run in the database once you call `ToList()` on it. Note that you have to pass in the same context to both of the repositories in order for this to work.

I recommend that you check out the Unit Of Work design pattern as well. It helps a lot when dealing with multiple repositories.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

This is a more structured and better maintainable way of handling transactions when it comes to multiple entity sets, and promotes better separation of concerns.

Hope I understood your problem correctly and this helps.

Comment: And what purpose exactly does "Repository" serves here?

Comment: I was just trying to answer the question: joins when using repository.
I agree that on their own respositories aren't very useful. That's why I included a link to an implementation with UoW. Add the UoW, add some interfaces and use a DI container, and you can totally separate your BLL from your DAL. In my experience this is good, because you can mock your interfaces more easily than a DbContext for testing and you can replace the whole data access technology. We used this in our projects before and now we can move to EFCore and enjoy the performance benefits without having to retest the BLL.

Comment: @AkosNagy Well explained my vote up for you sir. That's exactly i am going for, Using UoW And Dependency injection Pattern, i just need to get the pieces together right first. Forgive me for asking but you know any good tutorial on UoW and Mixing it with Dependency injection?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't come across any comprehensive tutorial on both. The link in my post is a reference for me about UoW and repository. My choice of DI container is Autofac, so the Autofac documentation is my reference there.
What is the technology you're using? I might have some ASP.NET Web API samples lying around, if that would be any help for you.

Comment: @AkosNagy Actually i'm using web api atm mixed with angularJS as a Single Page Application, it would definitely help mate :)

Comment: @Evk Thanks mate :)

Comment: @Evk Yes, that is a totally valid point. Again, I think it is much harder to mock the DbContext properly, as it is to mock your own interfaces (but that might be just me). And another reason to use this is to totally abstract away EF, so one day you can change to EFCore (like I'm doing now) or maybe NHibernate or whatever.

Comment: @Valkyriee OK, I am going to look for the examples and share them on GitHub. Give me some time and stay tuned :)

Comment: I'm not against Repository, that's reasonable pattern which is useful for example to cache query results or just abstract away EF. That is generic repository (repository per entity type) which does not make any sense to me still.

Comment: @Evk So you're idea is that Repository should be type-agnostic. I have to say, I've never used it this way. I just cannot see how you would distinguish between your type. How would you specify that you want the Student with PK=1 or the Standard with PK=1 if you query by Id? Or how could you List your Students or your Standards? Do you have separate methods, like a ListStudents() and a ListStandards() in the same repository class? Can you post some samples to see how this integrates with a business logic layer?

Comment: **When** I use repository, I do it like this yes. I do that usually only when I need to cache query results. For general usage I just use EF directly because it already implements unit of work _and_ each DbSet is already generic repository. This answer http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126/253633 more or less reflects what I think about this. There what I do is called service pattern though, not repository, but I don't think name is too important.

Comment: @Evk I see your point. For me the ability to separate business logic from EF completely and mocking more easily are still crucial design considerations. Thanks for taking the time to explain your approach, nice to meet other schools of thought.

Comment: @Valkyriee Check out the sample at https://github.com/conwid/RepositoryUoWSample Please be advised that this is just a project I use when I teach software design courses, so there are a few things which are not entirely thought out. Should help you to get started though.

Comment: @AkosNagy Thank you! It's more than enough for now!

Comment: Thanks bro! @AkosNagy

Answer (score -2):

I took this query where I was using Entity Framework

```
var result = (from metattachType in _dbContext.METATTACH_TYPE
                join lineItemMetattachType in _dbContext.LINE_ITEM_METATTACH_TYPE on metattachType.ID equals lineItemMetattachType.METATTACH_TYPE_ID
                where (lineItemMetattachType.LINE_ITEM_ID == lineItemId && lineItemMetattachType.IS_DELETED == false
                && metattachType.IS_DELETED == false)
                select new MetattachTypeDto()
                {
                    Id = metattachType.ID,
                    Name = metattachType.NAME
                }).ToList();
```

and changed it into this where I'm using the repository pattern
Linq

```
            return await _attachmentTypeRepository.GetAll().Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
                .Join(_lineItemAttachmentTypeRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.LineItemId == lineItemId && !x.IsDeleted),
                attachmentType => attachmentType.Id,
                lineItemAttachmentType => lineItemAttachmentType.MetattachTypeId,
                (attachmentType, lineItemAttachmentType) => new AttachmentTypeDto
                {
                    Id = attachmentType.Id,
                    Name = attachmentType.Name
                }).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Linq-to-sql

```
            return (from attachmentType in _attachmentTypeRepository.GetAll()
                    join lineItemAttachmentType in _lineItemAttachmentTypeRepository.GetAll() on attachmentType.Id equals lineItemAttachmentType.MetattachTypeId
                    where (lineItemAttachmentType.LineItemId == lineItemId && !lineItemAttachmentType.IsDeleted && !attachmentType.IsDeleted)
                    select new AttachmentTypeDto()
                    {
                        Id = attachmentType.Id,
                        Name = attachmentType.Name
                    }).ToList();
```

Also, please know that Linq-to-Sql is 14x faster than Linq...

[image]

Comment: There is no difference in Query and Method syntax. It's just syntax sugar and it's being translated to the same expression trees. The difference in time is just because SQL server has cached the query.